# Find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ if $z=z(x,y)$, $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The total derivatives are:
$$dz=(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})_ydx+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})_xdy$$
$$dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$$
$$dy=\frac{dy}{dt}dt$$
Substituting into the first equation gives:
$$dz=(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})_y\frac{dx}{dt}dt+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})_x\frac{dy}{dt}dt$$

is it acceptable to simply divide by $dt$ now? Or is there a more correct way of obtaining $\frac{dz}{dt}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Just use the chain rule
$$
\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}.
$$

Proof. Suppose $t$ changes by $\Delta t$. Then $x,y$ changes by $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ and $z$ changes by $\Delta z$ and
$$
\Delta z=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\Delta y+\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon_2\Delta y,
$$
where $\epsilon_{1,2}\to0$ as $\Delta x,\Delta y\to0$.
Then
$$
\frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}+\epsilon_1\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}+\epsilon_2\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}.
$$
If $x(t), y(t)$ differentiable at $t$, then
$$
\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{dx}{dt}, \lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}=\frac{dy}{dt},
$$
hence
$$
\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}.
$$
$z(x(t),y(t))$ is differentiable at $t$.

Comment: I am mean to derive that rather than just use it

Comment: @user3764899 Okay Ive added the proof above.